# NODE-Red parse data from webpage

Tags: parsing, node-red

I need to get data from online html table, parse it and find some values in it. The needed data is in class `<table class="zjrtbl" border="0">`. [This is the page I want to parse.](http://jizdnirady.idnes.cz/ceskebudejovice/zjr/?date=9.12.2016%20P%C3%A1&l=Trol%205&f=Strakonick%C3%A1%20-%20obchodn%C3%AD%20z%C3%B3na&t=Ro%C5%BEnov%20-%20to%C4%8Dna&wholeweek=true&ttn=CesBud&submit=true)It is an timetable of local bus stop.

1. How do I get this table to some variable to work with?
2. How do I parse the data so I will have let say 2D array of this table?

---

EDIT 2:

I have now this setup:

```
[{"id":"a9fffc.914a1008","type":"inject","z":"2988145.2ee976c","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":120,"y":140,"wires":[["889103ea.58886"]]},{"id":"889103ea.58886","type":"http request","z":"2988145.2ee976c","name":"","method":"GET","ret":"txt","url":"http://jizdnirady.idnes.cz/ceskebudejovice/zjr/?date=9.12.2016%20P%C3%A1&l=Trol%205&f=Strakonick%C3%A1%20-%20obchodn%C3%AD%20z%C3%B3na&t=Ro%C5%BEnov%20-%20to%C4%8Dna&wholeweek=true&ttn=CesBud&submit=true","tls":"","x":290,"y":140,"wires":[["9e5d61b1.d8747"]]},{"id":"9e5d61b1.d8747","type":"html","z":"2988145.2ee976c","name":"","tag":".zjrtbl","ret":"text","as":"single","x":430,"y":140,"wires":[["2ff681d4.5dcade"]]},{"id":"db94b76f.32ea58","type":"http in","z":"2988145.2ee976c","name":"","url":"/idos","method":"get","swaggerDoc":"","x":120,"y":100,"wires":[["889103ea.58886"]]},{"id":"5c2e34b0.692dbc","type":"http response","z":"2988145.2ee976c","name":"http","x":1170,"y":140,"wires":[]},{"id":"a9aa5336.dbaaa","type":"function","z":"2988145.2ee976c","name":"connector","func":"msg.payload = msg.payload;\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":840,"y":140,"wires":[["d8ed8e61.482"]]},{"id":"65013729.cd6df8","type":"function","z":"2988145.2ee976c","name":"split to array","func":"var arr = msg.payload.replace(/\\s+/g, ' ').split(' ');\nmsg.arr = arr;\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":690,"y":140,"wires":[["a9aa5336.dbaaa"]]},{"id":"daa81b7.bdcc1e8","type":"debug","z":"2988145.2ee976c","name":"payload","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"payload","x":1180,"y":180,"wires":[]},{"id":"2ff681d4.5dcade","type":"split","z":"2988145.2ee976c","name":"","splt":"","x":550,"y":140,"wires":[["65013729.cd6df8"]]},{"id":"d8ed8e61.482","type":"function","z":"2988145.2ee976c","name":"assemble array","func":"msg.payload = \"\";\nfor (var i = 0; i < msg.arr.length; i++) {\n    msg.payload += \"[\" + msg.arr[i] + \"]\";\n}\n\nmsg.statusCode = 200;\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":1000,"y":140,"wires":[["5c2e34b0.692dbc","daa81b7.bdcc1e8"]]}]
```

and it looks good now, but there is one more glitch... it does not separate hours from minutes...

Comment: I have an http request node, which outputs the whole timetable webpage connected to http response, so I can view it on my local server, but I do not know how to select the right class and convert the table to array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is notoriously difficult to parse, it's not always proper XML so things like XPath tend to fail.

The HTML node allows you to use CSS style selectors to grab bits of webpages. So something like this may get you closer.

```
[{"id":"b5b2b310.4dfc5","type":"inject","z":"59370ac1.51144c","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":138.5,"y":120,"wires":[["d7e0478a.997b8"]]},{"id":"d7e0478a.997b8","type":"http request","z":"59370ac1.51144c","name":"","method":"GET","ret":"txt","url":"http://jizdnirady.idnes.cz/ceskebudejovice/zjr/?date=9.12.2016%20P%C3%A1&l=Trol%205&f=Strakonick%C3%A1%20-%20obchodn%C3%AD%20z%C3%B3na&t=Ro%C5%BEnov%20-%20to%C4%8Dna&wholeweek=true&ttn=CesBud&submit=true","tls":"","x":332.5,"y":141,"wires":[["a8ff0654.6ac8d"]]},{"id":"a8ff0654.6ac8d","type":"html","z":"59370ac1.51144c","name":"","tag":".zjrtbl","ret":"html","as":"single","x":530.5,"y":146,"wires":[["984182c2.bb29e8"]]},{"id":"984182c2.bb29e8","type":"debug","z":"59370ac1.51144c","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":752.5,"y":205,"wires":[]}]
```

This will pull out just the table, you could then use another HTML node to pull out other parts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is great.